# parsing a config.ini file in python

Tags: python, config

so I have a config.ini file which I have to parse and use in my python script, I basically need to run a loop to get the REPOS_TO_CHECK in my script, can anyone help out in how to parse the file and run it in a loop in my script to get the REPOS_TO_CHECK parameters. Thanks.

```
GITHUB_URL = 'https://api.github.com'
GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'xxx'
REPOS_TO_CHECK = [
    ('org1', 'repo1'),
    ('org2', 'repo2'),]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) library.

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
```